# Write/Append to S3 bucket in Golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

The application I'm working on currently uses the Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper for PHP in order to write log messages to an S3 bucket and I need to port it over to Golang. Is there an equivilent to this in Go? The `PutObject` method overwrites all the contents and I want to just append. In PHP we are using `fopen()` and `fwrite()` to append a string to an existing bucket. I was hoping I could just do

```
os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
```

but I get an error saying the file doesn't exist. I tried using both `s3://` and the `https://` link to the log file.

Here's the Amazon example for PHP:

```
$stream = fopen('s3://bucket/key', 'w');
fwrite($stream, 'Hello!');
fclose($stream);
```

Comment: S3 does not support append.  Even the S3Manager that gets around the 5GB per chunk limit by putting up a bunch of chunk and appending them (behind the scenes) into one big file doesn't give the capability.  It may be the case that the file basically does not really exist at all until the last byte has been sent and the file handle is closed.

Comment: Have you checked the official aws documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/ and more specifically the S3 documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/

Comment: @Rob somehow it's doing the streaming thing in PHP though, so I'm confused...

Comment: @reticentroot yeah, I've combed through the docs but I can't find any streamer wrapper or anything that would return a file pointer

Answer (score 2):

As @Rob mentioned, S3 doesn't support append operation https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=540395.

The only way is download object and upload the new one using aws-sdk or minio (https://github.com/minio/minio). I suppose, PHP wrapper make the same under the hood.

The sample with minio:

```
s3Client, err := minio.New("s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE", "YOUR-SECRET-KEY-HERE", true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

reader, err := s3Client.GetObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer reader.Close()

// Change your data

n, err := s3Client.PutObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname", reader, "application/octet-stream")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Comment: I still haven't found an equivilent to PHP so, yeah, I just basically did what @BayRinat suggested and downloaded the file with GetObjectInput, parsed the contents and appended a new log message, converted it to bytes, then used PutObject to replace it on S3.

Comment: Is this limitation still in place? Append is important, especially if the file is very large.